# Error 404 when trying to use the Firebase UI for the firestripe example code

Tags: firebase, user-interface

I am following the instructions exactly for using firebase to process stripe payments at https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe however when I deploy the application the code breaks on just importing the firebase ui. The error message is within the firebaseui.css and firebaseui.js files and it says "Failed toe load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()". I havent been able to find anything else online about this, has anyone else run into this problem? Thank you!

[image]